# Type narrowing breaks when accessing an object property with bracket notation

Tags: typescript, properties, type-narrowing

Why do tests 1 and 2 work here, but test 3 shows a compiler error at `foo[barConst]++`: 'Object is possibly "undefined".'? I often need to access properties via bracket notation and thus like to have constants for these properties, but TypeScript doesn't allow this. It also doesn't work with `const enum`s. Is it a bug or is there a good reason for the error?

```js
const barConst = 'bar';

interface Foo {
    [barConst]?: number;
}

function test1(foo?: Foo) {
    if (foo && foo.bar) {
        foo.bar++;
    }
}

function test2(foo?: Foo) {
    if (foo && foo['bar']) {
        foo['bar']++;
    }
}

function test3(foo?: Foo) {
    if (foo && foo[barConst]) {
        foo[barConst]++; // compiler error: 'Object is possibly "undefined".'
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mb0jow)

Comment: I just copied your code, and it works correctly.  check if in your tsconfig file strict option is true or false. maybe, this is a problem

Comment: Can confirm, it works with `strictNullChecks` disabled. Why, though? P.S. disabling this setting is not an option for me.

Comment: foo[barConst] inside test3 will be evaluated in runtime. just because is inside a function (easy explanation).  interface Foo is not known for type checking when you are passing into test3 function. for test1 and test2, you explicitly checked for a value of the input parameter foo, so compiler does not complain. 
If you update you question, what is the use case for this, maybe I can help you find another solution.

Comment: Are you looking for dynamic keys for the Foo interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Narrowing the property access via computed propertyNames/literal expressions seems to be not possible currently. Have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) and its [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26424), also [that issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29042).

You can narrow property access in bracket notation with string literals like for example `foo["bar"]`. Dynamic expressions like `foo[barConst]` don't work. Assigning `foo[barConst]` to a variable and working/narrowing down this variable instead is an alternative, but costs an additional declaration.

In your case the simplest solution would be to just cast the expression with non-null assertion operator `!`. As you do a pre-check for a falsy value, you are safe here:

```
function test3(foo?: Foo) {
    if (foo && foo[barConst]) {
        foo[barConst]!++; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the release of [TypeScript 4.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#control-flow-analysis-for-element-access) due to its improvements to the control flow analysis for bracketed element access, the original code no longer results in a compiler error because the `foo && foo[barConst]` guard now correctly narrows the `foo[barConst]` access to be of type `number`.

See PR [#40617](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45974) for more details on the CFA update overall.

[4.7 Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBknnm)

Answer (score 0):

Continue of comment discussions. (I still do not know what are you looking for) 
you can try something like this:

```
type barConst = 'bar';

type Foo<K extends string> = Record<K, number>;

function test3(foo?: Foo<barConst>) {
  if (typeof foo !== 'undefined') {
    foo['bar']++;
  }
}
let x: Foo<barConst> = { bar: 2 };

test3(x);
console.log(x);
```

You can have autocomplete and no compiler error. 
Still, please Update your question.