# Why doesn't TypeScript know that this array item is not null?

Tags: javascript, typescript, narrowing

I'm new to TypeScript and I find it great so far. However, I don't quite understand why its narrowing mechanism can't handle certain situation.

Let's say we have a Fruit type and an array of `Fruit | null`:

```js
interface Fruit {
    name: string;
}

const fruits: (Fruit | null)[] = [
    { name: 'banana' },
    null,
    { name: 'apple' },
];
```

Now, I just want to log a name of certain fruit, if it's not `null`:

```js
// Setting number type to prevent literal type 0:
const index: number = 0;

if (fruits[index] !== null) {
    console.log(fruits[index].name); // All good!
}
```

However, if I just copy `const` value from `let`, it's no longer working:

```js
let indexLet = 0;
const indexConst = indexLet;

if (fruits[indexConst] !== null) {
    console.log(fruits[indexConst].name); // Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)
}
```

I know how to fix it, this is not the point. I'm trying to understand why TypeScript can't handle `fruits[indexConst] !== null` condition as expected.

[Here's a TS playground reproducing the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJQK7DMg3skOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5kBfAWACh2EB7EK5GTNgrkAFOiw4APgQwAbWQEoA2gF1kAXmSr67dgHo9yAMJwKKAIzkAqhTrI4yAAbdeYR8gBucGnABGsiAA6fUMAZQgwMDsQDCJfaGQwAE8ABxQwLmQUqAgPCHBkWWxoOFlE1JQABlJOHj5QABMIAA9yGLiEzUqdDjZgGGQRAQkKJUaWtQBCdU0Y%20QU8dmRl5BcKLgDA2S5aIcEwUfHmlUDCEgVGA2QAQXlkWi4uBsn2Vl6rkzNkACZrWxBaPYnGs3J5vMA-AFkAB3AAWXC%20XlkGBQwAolAi-CgXCIQMcAVBXh8-iC7AJyCOABkIm1YvEoBpkN1aq4KSAms0jHUcJoqREeux%20oNhkIxuyWlzXFMZjJ5os2CtVnUNkFtrsRQcxRzJVQTmcIBdkFcAPK%20ABWEAQODRWQRtn8SWQAHI5rInYEDiJvgBWADM5gUryAA).

Comment: That's peculiar... It looks like there's some of the "mutability" of the `indexLet` variable leaking into your `indexConst`. Frankly, that looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @Cerbrus yeah, however even if the mutability leaked, it still would be strange. TypeScript usually doesn't mind the mutability: `let foo: string | null = 'abc'; if (foo !== null) console.log(foo.toLocaleLowerCase());` - this is fine.

Comment: What confuses me is if you'd replace the `= indexLet` with just `= 0`, it's fine... That makes no sense, the source of the value shouldn't matter in the assignment.

Comment: @Cerbrus exactly. I actually simplified my real life use case, where I used one array's indexes to work with another one's values.

Comment: I think you can open an issue for this problem, IMO it looks like a bug.

Comment: [Here's a playground for it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJQK7DMg3skOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG5kBfAWACh2EB7EK5GTNgrkAFOiw4APgQwAbWQEoA2gF1kAXmSr67dgHo9yAMJwKKAIzkAqhTrI4yAAbdeYR8gBucGnABGsiAA6fUMAZQgwMDsQDCJfaGQwAE8ABxQwLmQUqAgPCHBkWWxoOFlE1JQABlJOHj5QABMIAA9yGLiEzUqdDjZgGGQRAQkKJUaWtQBCdU0Y+QU8dmRl5BcKLgDA2S5aIcEwUfHmlUDCEgVGA2QAQXlkWi4uBsn2Vl6rkzNkACZrWxBaPYnGs3J5vMA-AFkAB3AAWXC+XlkGBQwAolAi-CgXCIQMcAVBXh8-iC7AJyCOABkIm1YvEoBpkN1aq4KSAms0jHUcJoqREeux+oNhkIxuyWlzXFMZjJ5os2CtVnUNkFtrsRQcxRzJVQTmcIBdkFcAPK+ABWEAQODRWQRtn8SWQAHI5rInYEDiJvgBWADM5gUryAA)

Comment: @Cerbrus thanks, I was about to add the link myself, but you were quicker :)

Comment: You're welcome! Faster than my own shadow ;-)

Comment: Looks like assigning `fruits[indexConst]` to a temp variable before the condition silences the error, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57891347/941240). Could it be a duplicate of yours then?

Comment: @WiktorZychla yes, it looks like a similar problem. I also know that using a `const` to store indexed value works. The purpose of this question is educational.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with `let`, since [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wj1x6W) has no `let` and has the same behavior.  I'd say that what's happening here is that your original version only works since TS4.7 [introduced](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#control-flow-analysis-for-bracketed-element-access) support for bracketed element access type guards via [ms/TS#45974](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45974), ad that the second version doesn't work because that support didn't target copying like this. ...

Comment: ... I don't know that it's a *bug*; maybe a missing feature or limitation (how far should the compiler be expected to track copying?). Does this fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? Please mention @jcalz if you reply to notify me.

Comment: @jcalz well, I feel like it's two issues in one. One being weak tracking of indexes, another one being strange distinction between `const` and `const` derived from a variable. They should behave the same imo.

Comment: Could you then [edit] the question so that it's clearly about single issue?  Which issue do you want this question to be about primarily?  Either way, this is occurring because your example isn't one of use cases [ms/TS#45974](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45974) was meant to address; it seems like it was specifically to target computed properties whose names couldn't easily be mentioned any other way (like `Symbol`). It would be nice if narrowing would always work when indexing via the same `const` multiple times, but that is still apparently a missing feature.

Comment: Please let me know if you want to see an answer written up; I can't quite tell from your response if you think I've not identified the cause of the situation.